# Python Coordinate system question for centering drawn objects

Tags: python, pygame

We would like to create a rectangle with width `w` and height `h`, on a surface whose width is `a` and whose height is `b`.

What would be the values of left, top, width, height that we have to pass to the `pygame.Rect` function, if the rectangle needs to be at a distance x_offset from the left edge of the surface and centered vertically on the surface?

I got this question and I know that left would be equal to x_offset but I have no idea how to figure out any of the other ones I've tried drawing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just create your `Rect` object first with the values you know:

```
rect = pygame.Rect(x_offset, 0, w, h)
```

and center the rect by using its `centery` attribute:

```
rect.centery = the_other_surface.get_rect().centery
```

Answer (score 0):

It can help if you rename the variables into something readable.
For example:

```
rect_width = w
rect_height = h

surface_width = a
surface_height = b
```

rect_width and rect_height will be the Rect's width and height.
The x_offset will be the left.

```
rect_left = x_offset
```

To center it vertically, find the vertical center:

```
surface_center_v = surface_height / 2
```

Then place the rectangle there.

```
rect_top = surface_center_v
```

However this only places the rectangle's top edge, and we want the vertical center.
So adjust the rectangle's position upwards by half of the rectangle's height, to make the rectangle's vertical center align with the surface's vertical center.

```
rect_top -= rect_height / 2
```

Now you have all of rect_left, rect_top, rect_width and rect_height.

Answer (score 0):

To use all of the specified variables (rather than hard-coding absolute sizes into the program), I would make use of pygame's Rectangle object for both the surface and the rectangle we want to draw.

```
import pygame
from time import sleep
pygame.init()

# Declare our variables and initialize
a,b = 0,0 # Declare screen dimensions.
w,h = 0,0 # Declare rectangle dimensions.
x,y = 0,0 # Declare placement locations on screen surface.

# Now set specific values to our variables
a = 500 # Screen Width
b = 500 # Screen Height

# We could use any surface here (such as for a sprite), but let's use the screen.
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((a,b),32) # Create a screen surface of size a X b
screen.fill(pygame.Color("DARKBLUE"))      # Fill it with Dark Blue.
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()            # Create a rectangle object for the screen.

w = 200 # Make the rectangle 200 wide.
h = 100 # Make the rectangle 100 high.
rec = pygame.Rect((x,y,w,h)) # Create a rectangle object for our drawn rectangle.
# Rec holds all of the placement and size values for the rectangle we want to draw.
rec_color = (255,0,0) # Let's draw a red rectangle.

distance_x = 50 # Place the rectangle 50 pixels over from the left side of the screen.
rec.x = distance_x                # Set rec's x value equal to distance_x.
rec.centery = screen_rect.centery # Set rec's y value to center of the screen y-axis
# Pygame's Rectangle Object handles the calculations for us. NICE! 

pygame.draw.rect(screen,rec_color,rec,2) # Draw a rectangle on the screen using a line
                                         # that is 2-pixels wide. (Use 0 to fill.)
pygame.display.flip()                    # Show the screen.

print("\nrec =",rec,end="\n\n")          # Let's see rec's final values.
sleep(3)                                 # Sleep for 3 seconds.
exit()                                   # Quit
```